# MySQL-Workbench 6.3.6 can not display server status. Platform time_t error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and MySQL Server version: 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu). Everything works seemingly fine, but the sever status not.

The error message is: "Unhandled exception: timestamp out of range for platform time_t". It is probably a Python error.

[image]

When i run mysql through the shell, status reports the following:

[image]

Any clues why my uptime is screwed? 
How does one fix the uptime in order to avoid the platform time_t error in the Workbench application?

My Uptime:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess - do you have NTP sync enabled? I am having same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 as a Hyper-V guest. When Ubuntu boots, MySQL is being started prior to time sync and gets nice eternal uptime. Simple solution - service mysql restart.
Proper solution - make sure mysql service starts after ntp sync.